# getting tables name from tabular DB using Analysis Services AMO-TOM

Tags: sql-server, ssas, tabular

I'm trying to get list of names of tables in my Tabular DB using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular in the following script:

```
Server server = new Server();

        server.Connect("m_server");
        Database db = server.Databases["m_DB"];

        foreach (Table tbl in db.Model.Tables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table: ", tbl.Name.ToString());

        }
```

I'm getting only blanks instead of names.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
..
Console.WriteLine("Table: " + tbl.Name.ToString());
..